# Prove Least Upper Bound of a Set

Tags: real-analysis, upper-lower-bounds

How do we prove for $$S = \{ y \in \mathbb R | y^3 \leq x\}$$ $x$ is $\alpha^3$ for which $\alpha$ is the least upper bound of S? I try to rule out $\alpha^3 < x$ and $\alpha^3 > x$ but I have no idea how to prove? (Note: assume we do not know the existence of cube root)

Comment: Use density of the real numbers

Comment: Do you mind further explain how to use that ?

Comment: For the first one, there exists $z\in\mathbb R$ such that $\alpha < z < \sqrt[3]{x}$. This means there is a member of the set greater than $\alpha$

Comment: Sorry. I forget to mention that we have to assume we do not know the existence of cube root. See edited question above.

Comment: Hint: if $\alpha^3 > x$, then so is (\alpha- \epsilon)^3$ for $\epsilon$ sufficiently small, and if $\alpha^3 < x$ then same thing for $(\alpha + \epsilon)^3$.

Comment: If $\alpha^3<x$ then show that there is a $y$ such that $\alpha^3<y^3<x$ so that $y\in S$ and $y>\alpha$, a contradiction. The case $\alpha^3>x$ is slightly more tricky but involves arguments of a similar nature and one needs to find a $z$ with $x<z^3<\alpha^3$ in this case.